# Debugging ASP.NET Core is not working on VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm using visual studio.

1. 4.5 ASP.NET application

I see the dropdown showing debugging options only contains web browsers (see screenshot). When I select **Start Debugging**, press **F5**, or select one of the browsers from the dropdown list, the debugging process starts and the execution stops at each of my breakpoints.

[image]

1. ASP.NET Core

I see the dropdown list contains the following options (screenshot).

[image]

When I press F5 when IIS Express is selected, I get a showbox with a message saying "**debug is starting...**"  (see screenshot). That showbox doesn't disappear until I kill Visual Studio process.

[image]

If, instead of IIS Express, I chose myproject name, in this case IdentityDemo, then the page is displayed. However, there's no debugging process started.

I need help with debugging.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Is it VS2015 with the latest preview version?

Comment: It's VS2015 with whatever latest update  available, update 3 or 4.

Comment: Already restarted VS2015 I assume? Restarted PC? Rebuild/cleaned solution? No dotnet-watch currently active? Just some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same issue, however i stumbled upon the following page: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/8491/aspnet-core-app-fails-to-run-after-updating-to-lat.html

The issue was that I had updated the Microsoft.NETCore.App Nuget package to 1.1.0 but I only had the 1.0.1 SDK installed (This can be shown by typing dotnet into a cmd prompt).  After installing the 1.1 SDK (https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current) and restarting Visual Studio, I was then able to debug via IISExpress.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating the AspNetCore.MVC to 1.1.0 version using nuget. I tried the update update the Microsoft.NETCore.App to 1.0.1 version from 1.0.0.
By mistake, I changed the version number in project.json file to 1.1.0

```
After changing the version of Microsoft.NETCore.App in the project.json file to 1.0.1 , the issue was fixed.
```

[image: Fix]